# How to get elements from Generic Object?

Tags: java, object

```
public void method(Object variable){
    System.out.println(variable.toString());
}
```

When I invoke the method above, I get the following output:

```
<Heading element1=value1 element2=value2 element3=value3/>
```

How can I get only 'value3' from this object's toString method without resorting to String operations or Regex with the Matcher class?

Comment: You really don't, unless you do some `instanceof` checks first and then cast `variable` to a specific type.

Comment: @luk2302 This `method` is actually an overridded interface method where the definition of the method is to take generic Object as a parameter.

Comment: Then your interface is really bad and you need to go with the `instanceof` route and check wether the variable is an instance of `YourClassWhichHasAnElement3`.

Comment: Note: the proper answer: use a better interface then. The whole point of good OOP is to create USEFUL abstractions. Relying on `Object` as method parameter is the exact opposite of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been remarked in the comments, you cannot do what you're attempting without using a regex or at least casting the Object to something more specific and then retrieving the property value you're looking for.

You might want to try something like

```
public void method(Object variable){
   if (variable instanceof MyClass){
      MyClass mc = (MyClass) variable;
      System.out.println(mc.getMyProperty());   
   } else {
      //... regex implementation ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what luk2302 said in the comments. And it seems to be the only way I have solve the problem.